# Symfony 4.1 : UniqueEntity validation on ArrayCollection

Tags: php, symfony, validation, symfony-forms, symfony4

I have a parent entity Product, how can be in many Family.

Family property is display as CollectionType. The purpuse is to create as many families as we want, but the name of each family must be unique for the product.

It work fine when i have data in family table ; but when it's empty and i add two family for my product at once, with the same name, the @UniqueEntity is not triggered ; otherwise it's the ORM uniqueConstraints how respond.

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO
>   family (name, max_product, required, created_at,
>   updated_at, promotion_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   ["toto", 1, 0, "2018-12-06 14:54:13", "2018-12-06 14:54:13", 1]:

Below a sample of my enties :

```
/**
 * @var Family[]|ArrayCollection
 *
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Family::class, mappedBy="product", fetch="LAZY", cascade={"persist", "remove"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"id" = "ASC"})
 * @Assert\Valid
 */
private $families;
```

And

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ProductCollectionFamilyRepository::class)
 * @ORM\Table(name="product_collection_family",
 *     indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_FAMILY_NAME", columns={"name"})},
 *     uniqueConstraints={
 *        @ORM\UniqueConstraint(columns={"promotion_id", "name"})
 *    }
 * )
 *
 * 2.5.4.5RG02
 *
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"product", "name"},
 *     errorPath="name",
 *     message="backend.error.label.family.unique_entity"
 * )
 */
class Family
{
    use TimestampableEntity;
    use ProductCollectionTrait;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Length(min="1", max="100", minMessage="backend.error.label.short", maxMessage="backend.error.label.long")
     */
    private $name;

   /**
    * @var Product
    *
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class, inversedBy="families", fetch="LAZY")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
    * @Assert\NotBlank
    */
   private $product;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: using UniqueEntity on 2 fields make it unique but within two fields not one so if you enter

product A, name B
product A, name C

it won't trigger the constraint. Isn't it your problem?

Comment: But this is not uniqueEntity error. Unique entity error message should be like this SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

Comment: @hous Indeed i forgot a part of the message, i got this message too :

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '7-test' for key 'UNIQ_E346EBFE139DF1945E237E06'

Comment: @Robert
The problem occurred when i add two or more family at once (it's a CollectionType form).

The purpose is to not have same family name the product. When i added then one by one, it's ok ; but not when i try all at once.

Comment: then you can use form validation, can't you? :)

Comment: @Robert i will try with custom validate Callback to check double in the arraycollection.

But my purpuse was to use tools give by the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In ordre to do that, i just create a assert callback function that check elements in array collection, and then, build a violation.

```
/**
 * @Assert\Callback
 *
 * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
 * @param $payload
 */
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{
    $productFamilies = clone $this->getProductFamilies();
    $productFamiliesFiltered = $this->getProductFamilies()->filter(function ($currentProductFamily) use ($productFamilies) {
        // Remove current family from original collection
        $productFamilies->removeElement($currentProductFamily);
        foreach ($productFamilies as $data) {
            //we have same name ?
            if ($currentProductFamily->getName() === $data->getName()) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    });

    if (0 !== $productCollectionFiltered->count()) {
        $context->buildViolation('backend.error.label.product_family.unique_entity')
            ->atPath('productFamilies')
            ->addViolation();
    }
}
```